# Mantener los datos de un procedure en un modelo de datos C#

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando realizar una funcionalidad para llenar campos de un formulario con los datos que obtengo de un procedure

Ejecuto el procedure de la siguiente manera

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ColbertConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
           {
               cn.Open();

               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Credito_Abonos_Recibo", cn);
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idrecibo", idRecibo);

               SqlDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            }
```

lo que deseo hacer el que los nombres de todas las columnas que me generan en la consulta, queden con los respectivos datos en un modelo, para luego indicarle que:

```
labelRecibo.text = miModelo.idRecibo; // esto desde el codeBehind
```

mi modelo

```
namespace MvcApp.Models
{
    public class ResultProdecure
    {
        public decimal IdRecibo { get; set; }
        public int IdArticulo { get; set; }
        public string Bodega { get; set; }
        public int Disponible { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu codigo podria ser algo como esto

```
public ResultProdecure obtenerRecibo(decimal idRecibo)
{
    ResultProdecure result = null;

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ColbertConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Credito_Abonos_Recibo", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idrecibo", idRecibo);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if(reader.Read())
        {
            result = new ResultProdecure()
            {
                IdRecibo = Convert.ToDecimal(rader["IdRecibo"]),
                IdArticulo = Convert.ToInt32(rader["IdArticulo"]),
                Bodega = Convert.ToString(rader["Bodega"]),
                Disponible = Convert.ToInt32(rader["Disponible"]),
                Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(rader["Cantidad"]),
            };
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

como veras se usa el `if` con el reader para que se situe en el primer registro que encontrol, como filtras por if entendi que solo retorna una unica instancia

Igual no que queda claro porque el `IdRecibo` es decimal, si es una `key` no es un buen tipo de dato deberia ser `int`

Comment: me ha funcionado @Leandro. Gracias

Comment: como adicional @leandro como haría cuando la propiedad de IdRecibo sea null, para que no me genere error?

Comment: seria raro que justo ese campo sea null ya que es justamente por el cual estas aplicando un filtro, digo es el que pasas por parametro, pero bueno podrias validarlo `IdRecibo = reader["IdRecibo"] == DbNull.Value ? (decimal?)null : Convert.ToDecimal(reader["IdRecibo"])` pero ojo porque en este caso la propiedad debera ser del tipo `decimal?` o sea soportar `null`

Comment: es correcto, nunca sera nulo, solo queria saber como podria hacer la validacion pero termine haciéndola de otra manera